# Having trouble setting up Subversion with LDAP authentication

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, authentication, ldap

I am trying to setup an SVN repository using LDAP authentication. I have configured the SVN authentications in dav_svn.conf as outlined here: http://www.itguyonline.com/blog/2007/05/02/ldap-authentication-for-subversion-on-ubuntu-feisty/

My current configuration is like this:

```
<Location /svn>
    DAV svn

    SVNParentPath /mnt/svn

    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"

    AuthLDAPBindDN "<bind-url>"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword <bind-password>

    Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I got the bind url from Softerra LDAP Browser. Also, I know that the LDAP server is setup correct because we have had other services authenticating with it.

When I try to access the repository in my web browser, I can see the login dialog. However, when I enter a correct username and password, it just goes back to an empty login dialog again.

This is using port 389. When I change to 636, I get an internal server error after the login dialog.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Am I missing a key step?

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: prowser continuosly ask you for credentials because cannot verify authentication with ldap. First use any ldap browser (for example apache directory studio) and try connect to ldap using specified ports. another, you must create technical user for svn service. service will ask question to ldap using that user. password for his should never expire. another, you must specify base DN. Otherwise you must specify full DN path with user when browser asks you for credentials.